# Librem 5 Purism hardware buttons, software equivalent on GrapheneOS?

Tags: security

One of the best features of the Librem 5 Purism is it's hardware switches. Any possibility that a means exists that will allow me to do this on GrapheneOS? Software, rather than hardware, of course.

--Update--

Obviously not the same hardware also. It just seems to me that if it's a good idea to have these readily accessible in the first case then why not also the second? Is there an app or plugin something? What about shortcuts to settings items? Wouldn't something like this make a good intelligent default?

-- Update 2 --

I'm new around these parts so I can't respond to comments. The hardware switches on the Librem 5 turn off everything that you might consider a security risk. They are not programmable. The idea is that you can literally turn off your camera, cellular, etc. Know how having your camera turn on spontaneously creeps people out? Well you can just turn it off. Totally disabled because of a hardware switch such that software cannot turn it on. So if you are at a protest and you think "The Man" is tracking your cell, just flip a switch and turn it off. It's not the same if it's software, of course, but then again, GrapheneOS is pretty trustworthy as software goes. It's having those buttons readily available that I'm after. On a phone that is touted for security, I shouldn't have to dig for them, should I?

Comment: GrapheneOS is for Pixel devices only: https://grapheneos.org/faq#supported-devices

Comment: For those who don't know what those hardware switches do on Librem 5 Purism, could you explain more if there is something special about them? Is it like they can be customized whatever the user wants? (Considering that Librem 5 Purism does not run Android OS, so they have more freedom in designing their hardware and software.)

Comment: OK. Some magic has happened and now I can add comments. The hardware switches of the Librem 5 turn off anything that might become a security problem. WiFi,GPS, Cellular, Camera etc. etc. etc. They are not programmable. They are intended to override any possibility of software doing something the owner doesn't want with those services.